# Spring Roo: Showing related data depending on user choice

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I have University and Major entities. Each university has different majors and each major is for one university only.
The user should choose a university first and I need only the majors in the chosen university to be showed.

Major.java

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Major {

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

University.java

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class University {

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    /**
     */
    private String address;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Major> majors = new HashSet<Major>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Finders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/command-index.html#command-index-finder-commands) and [web finders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/command-index.html#command-index-web-finder-commands) commands should help you. This [post](http://spring.io/blog/2009/05/27/getting-started-with-spring-roo) (it's old but explain functionality) shows you who to use *Dynamic finders*.

In addition you can lock at *samples* folder included in Spring Roo  package.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but actually I didn't get it %100. I have in my University entity a findUniversitysByMajors(Set majors) finder, but how can I bind this finder to the change of university in a third entity for example?